# Kohana domain routes

Tags: php, dns, frameworks, routes, kohana

I can't set default route on my domain. I want mydomain.com to lead to mydomain.com/app/new

i have tried many route sets but nothing worked.

```
 Route::set('homePage', '')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'app',
    'action' => 'new',
));

Route::set("home","mydomain.com")
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'app',
    'action' => 'new',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'app',
    'action' => 'new',
));
```

Comment: The default route should be fine. Have you correctly set `base_path`, have you created the action & controller correctly? Do you get a 404 error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly set `base_url` (in `application/bootstrap.php`), e.g.

`Kohana::init(array(
 'base_url' =>'http://example.com/app/new/',
 ...
));`

Depending on how you're serving the site, you may also need to use `RewriteBase` within `.htaccess`.
`RewriteBase /app/new/` should do it.